# How did i detect non straight line?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have image with line drawn like below.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv3X2.png)

I want to split the image into smaller image base on the line drawn in the image.

I have tried using cv2.HoughLines to gain the line coordinate but I see that it can not fully detect all the line below is the image of the detected line using cv2.HoughLinesP

[detected line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knWDN.png)

As you can see it is not fully detected and also upon checking actually houghLines function detect one line as several line so I am confuse at how to put the line together in order to seperate the image.

Below is the code that I use to detect the line

```
img = cv2.imread("testImages.png")
img_copy = img.copy()
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray,150,200,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,cv2.HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC,np.pi/180,30,30,5)
```

EDIT :

The output i expected is actually to split/ cropped my image base on the line detected in the image as the sample i provided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hough detects straight lines. If your lines are not straight, you cannot use Hough. You need to find an alternate solution.

Comment: What output do you expect ??

Comment: @Cris Luengo actually using hough kinda work a bit now that i tested further from the several line detected by hough i rejoined all the line back through image processing. The thing is that when i join them back they become polygon which leave rooms for error a bit.